# how to run cmake file to generate .a file

Tags: cmake, cmake-gui, cmake-modules, cmake-custom-command

after running cmake ., I generate

```
bin           CMakeCache.txt     Makefile   
 CMakeFiles           config.h        lib              
     cmake_install.cmake
```

I need to pass .a file to a library, but I do not know where the `.a` file is generated and how

Comment: Running `cmake` only configures the project. For build it (compile files) you need to run `make` then.

Comment: I recommend adding [`install()` commands](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html) specifying relative paths for the install destinations; this allows you to use cmake functionality to copy the files below a dir you specify: `cmake -S source_dir -B build_dir && cmake --build build_dir && cmake --install build_dir --prefix install_dir` to build everything and "install" the build results using `install_dir` as path to resolve relative install paths against.